# Factoring a polynomial over finite field $\,F_3$ that has a root

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

A question I am struggling with.

We are asked to factor $\,f(x)=x^2+x+1$ over the field $F_3 =\{0,1,2\}$

So, I checked for a root, and I saw that $f(1) = 1^2+1+1 =0$ (because $3=0$ in $F_3$)

that means I can write f(x) as $(x-1)g(x)$ but how do i find $g(x)$?

I did polynomial division and I got that $x^2+x+1$ divided by $x-1$ over $F_3$ is equal to $x+2$

But $f(x)$ is not equal to $(x-1)(x+2)$. I could use some help

Comment: Of course $\;f(x)=(x-1)(x+2)\;$ in $\;\Bbb F_3[x]\;$ ...don't forget to do modulo three arithmetic!

Comment: As a remark, you may write $f(x)=(x+2)^2$ as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(x-1)(x+2)=x^2+2x-x-2=x^2+x-2=x^2+x+1$ in $F_3$.

Comment: $-2=1$ in $F3$? Why?

Comment: $-2\equiv 1\pmod 3$.